# How to split newline

Tags: jquery, split

I'm using jQuery, and I have a textarea. When I submit by my button I will alert each text separated by newline.
How to split my text when there is a newline?

```
  var ks = $('#keywords').val().split("\n");
  (function($){
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#data').submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           alert(ks[0]);
           $.each(ks, function(k){
              alert(k);
           });
        });
     });
  })(jQuery);
```

example input :

```
Hello
There
```

Result I want is :

```
alert(Hello); and
alert(There)
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Try initializing the `ks` variable inside your submit function.

```
  (function($){
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#data').submit(function(e){
           var ks = $('#keywords').val().split("\n");
           e.preventDefault();
           alert(ks[0]);
           $.each(ks, function(k){
              alert(k);
           });
        });
     });
  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: alert(k) only alerts the sequence number, not the value. You should alert(ks[k])

Comment: @hblackorby  Your comment, although relevant, is somewhat of a mute point as OP's primary issue here was scope and initialization of his variable "ks"

Answer (score 222):

You should parse newlines **regardless of the platform (operation system)**
This split is universal with regular expressions. You may consider using this:

```
var ks = $('#keywords').val().split(/\r?\n/);
```

E.g.

```
"a\nb\r\nc\r\nlala".split(/\r?\n/) // ["a", "b", "c", "lala"]
```

Comment: AFAIK this will work on Windows and Unix but not Mac prior to Mac OS X.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer by and far @oknoorap

Comment: This will not work if it uses a carriage return in Windows (^M$)

Answer (score 66):

It should be

```
yadayada.val.split(/\n/)
```

you're passing in a literal string to the split command, not a regex.

Comment: `"\n"` and `/\n/` are two ENTIRELY different things in JS. `"` = string, `/` = regex.

Comment: Yes, but what is the effective difference?  Don't `"\n"` and `/\n/` match the same things?

Comment: Both "\n" and /\n/ will work about the same, but depending on the source you are splitting, something like val.split(/[\r\n]+/) may be better. If your source has "\r\n" line-breaks then splitting on "\n" leaves the "\r" on the end which can cause problems.

Comment: works like a charm. I'm using react so I cant use jquery.

Comment: You might also want to [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the resulted strings to get rid of newline parts, such as `\r`

Answer (score 37):

Since you are using `textarea`, you may find \n or \r (or \r\n) for line breaks. So, the following is suggested:

`$('#keywords').val().split(/\r|\n/)`

ref: [check whether string contains a line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131072/check-whether-string-contains-a-line-break)

Comment: or, more specifically, `/\r?\n/` ... I think using `|` (or) would interleave empty results for CRLF line endings.

Comment: You're not going to see CR-only (`\r`) [line breaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation) anywhere on the modern web. The last place where they were widely used was in [ancient Mac OS versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Mac_OS) from nearly 20 years ago.

Answer (score 14):

Just

`var ks = $('#keywords').val().split(/\r\n|\n|\r/);`

will work perfectly.

Be sure `\r\n` is placed at the leading of the **RegExp** string, cause it will be tried first.

Comment: The `g` at the end of the regex isn't necessary

Answer (score 11):

The simplest and safest way to split a string using new lines, regardless of format (CRLF, LFCR or LF), is to **remove all carriage return characters** and **then split on the new line characters**. `"text".replace(/\r/g, "").split(/\n/);`

This ensures that when you have continuous new lines (i.e. `\r\n\r\n`, `\n\r\n\r`, or `\n\n`) the result will always be the same.

In your case the code would look like:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#data').submit(function (e) {
            var ks = $('#keywords').val().replace(/\r/g, "").split(/\n/);
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(ks[0]);
            $.each(ks, function (k) {
                alert(k);
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here are some examples that display the importance of this method:

```js
var examples = ["Foo\r\nBar", "Foo\r\n\r\nBar", "Foo\n\r\n\rBar", "Foo\nBar\nFooBar"];

examples.forEach(function(example) {
  output(`Example "${example}":`);
  output(`Split using "\n": "${example.split("\n")}"`);
  output(`Split using /\r?\n/: "${example.split(/\r?\n/)}"`);
  output(`Split using /\r\n|\n|\r/: "${example.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/)}"`);
  output(`Current method: ${example.replace(/\r/g, "").split("\n")}`);
  output("________");
});

function output(txt) {
  console.log(txt.replace(/\n/g, "\\n").replace(/\r/g, "\\r"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Move the `var ks = $('#keywords').val().split("\n");` inside the event handler
2. Use `alert(ks[k])` instead of `alert(k)`

---

```
  (function($){
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#data').submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           var ks = $('#keywords').val().split("\n");
           alert(ks[0]);
           $.each(ks, function(k){
              alert(ks[k]);
           });
        });
     });
  })(jQuery);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wZeWV/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Good'ol javascript:

```
 var m = "Hello World";  
 var k = m.split(' ');  // I have used space, you can use any thing.
 for(i=0;i<k.length;i++)  
    alert(k[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you initialize `ks`, the `value` hasn't been set.

You **need to fetch the value** when user submits the form. So you need to **initialize the `ks` inside the callback function**

```
(function($){
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#data').submit(function(e){
      //Here it will fetch the value of #keywords
         var ks = $('#keywords').val().split("\n");
         ...
      });
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example with `console.log` instead of `alert()`. It is more convenient :)

```
var parse = function(){
  var str = $('textarea').val();
  var results = str.split("\n");
  $.each(results, function(index, element){
    console.log(element);
  });
};

$(function(){
  $('button').on('click', parse);
});
```

You can try it [here](http://jsbin.com/unoner/edit#javascript,html)

Answer (score -1):

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#data').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.each($("#keywords").val().split("\n"), function(e, element) {
        alert(element);
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="keywords">Hello
World</textarea>
<input id="data" type="button" value="submit">
```

Comment: this approach is well covered by the existing answers

Comment: @KyleMit yeah, I go through those answers, most probable answers are similar due to basic concept of javascript, but I focus or concern with the line of code that is why I posted this answer...

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to pass any regular expression there. this works just fine..

```
 (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#data').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.each($("#keywords").val().split("\n"), function(e, element) {
            alert(element);
          });
        });
      });
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score -1):

In React Native, I have accomplish splitting by new line character via double back slashes, first one is as an escape character:

```
data = str.split("\\n");
```

Comment: Close! For it to work properly for me, I needed to remove the first escape character. str.split("\n")