# check whether string contains a line break

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have to get HTML of textarea and check whether it contains line break. How can i see whether it contain `\n` because the string return using `val()` does not contain `\n` and i am not able to detect it. I tried using `.split("\n")` but it gave the same result. How can it be done ?

One minute, IDK why when i add `\n` to textarea as value, it breaks and move to next line.

Comment: Are you sure that your html has `\n` but not `<br>`?

Comment: You just need to use `.val()` as it's input element. Also take into account line wrapping, which is NOT adding newline characters.

Comment: I didn't understand the downvote... this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: 1600 views later, I'm the +1? What's wrong you people? This is a nice question.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Line breaks in HTML aren't represented by `\n` or `\r`. They can be represented in lots of ways, including the `<br>` element, or any block element following another (`<p></p><p></p>`, for instance).

If you're using a `textarea`, you *may* find `\n` or `\r` (or `\r\n`) for line breaks, so:

```
var text = $("#theTextArea").val();
var match = /\r|\n/.exec(text);
if (match) {
    // Found one, look at `match` for details, in particular `match.index`
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/eyaroc/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/eyaroc/1/edit)

...but that's just `textarea`s, not HTML elements in general.

Comment: Is there a way to get the string index of the new line?

Comment: @rotaercz: Look up `RegExp#exec` and what it returns.

Comment: ECMAScript 2015 version: `myString.includes("\n")`

Comment: @FrancoRoura - To look specifically and only for `\n`, yeah.

Answer (score 15):

```
var text = $('#total-number').text();
var eachLine = text.split('\n');
  alert('Lines found: ' + eachLine.length);
  for(var i = 0, l = eachLine.length; i < l; i++) {
      alert('Line ' + (i+1) + ': ' + eachLine[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use this

```
var numberOfLineBreaks = (enteredText.match(/\n/g)||[]).length;
```