# Get next few lines after a word in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to parse an email body and get the next 3 lines after the word "Location" in javascript.

Here is my text:

Blah blah
other email content

Location:
1600 Pennsylvania Avenue
Washington, DC 20006
USA

So the first thing I know to do is use indexOf to parse for "Location" but how do I get the three lines after that?  Do I have to do a "split" of all lines in the text area and then use "\n" to somehow go to the next few lines? Do I have to use RegEx?

```
  var a = textarea;
  var b = a.split("\n");
  var c = b.indexOf("Location");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```js
var text = document.getElementById("input").value;

var stripped = text.replace(/[\s\S]+Location:[\r\n]+/gi, '');
var addressLines = stripped.trim().split(/[\r\n]+/);

console.log(addressLines);
```

```html
<textarea id="input">
Blah blah other email content

Location:
1600 Pennsylvania Avenue
Washington, DC 20006
USA
</textarea>
```

1. Remove everything before and including `Location:`
2. Split the remaining text on newlines.

Comment: what if text exist after third line `country name : USA`  ? `Location:
1600 Pennsylvania Avenue
Washington, DC 20006
USA

and this extra line
more extra line`

Comment: The OP gave no indication that's a possibility, but any lines after USA will be array entries in the result. Which may be a good thing if there's a address-related line after `USA`.

Comment: yes you are right, I also though same , don't know who don't like my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you split the text by [`\n` and/or `\r` using a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15131117/4297364) as the [answer by @Cerbrus does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45994904/4297364) (as `lines`), you can loop line by line using an index (`i`) to access the text in the current line.

Once you have verified that the line contains `Location` (using `line.indexOf('Location') !== -1)`, you can then get the following three lines using `lines.slice(i + 1, i + 4)`.

```js
function getLocation() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('text');
    var lines = textarea.value.split(/[\r\n]+/);
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i ++) {
        var line = lines[i];
        if(line.indexOf('Location') !== -1) {
            var nextThreeLines = lines.slice(i + 1, i + 4);
            console.log(nextThreeLines);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#text {
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text">
Blah blah other email content

Location:
1600 Pennsylvania Avenue
Washington, DC 20006
USA
</textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Get Location</button>
```

Comment: Can you provide any feedback?

Comment: Please do not re-post your answers to get around downvotes. Such actions are frowned upon, and may even result in a answer ban if you do it regularly.

Comment: Feedback: `for` loop that iterates over _all_ lines, regardless of if a result has been found already. Splitting on a `"\n"` literal instead of `/[\r\n]/` may be a compatibility concern.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thank you for the warning and the feedback.

Could you share a use case that would break the above example?

Comment: @Cerbrus I've updated the answer to also take `/r` into account. Could you share any other parts of the answer that you think I can improve?

Comment: You're aware that some systems use `\r\n`? Your code wouldn't work for those. Try this:  `"foo\r\nbar".split(/\r|\n/)`.

Comment: @Cerbrus I've updated the answer once again. Thank you for helping me improve the answer.

Comment: thanks @Cerbus your code worked for me! the only thing i had to do was put a join() in the nextThreeLines array because I wanted to return a string instead of array! All set!