# php ajax response text

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this AJAX sign up form, and I want to make a gear wheel play like [that](https://gyazo.com/3d4bf9ea178320a2cf3de1f760569865)

whenever the server has signed up i want this bar to change to green, so what's I've done is echo the names of the function I wanted to call like so:

```
            echo "passed";
            if ($query = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO business(password , username , bname) VALUES(? , ? , ?)")) {
                $query->bind_param("sss" , $password , $username , $bname );
                $query->execute();
            } else {
                printf("ErrorMessage: %s \n" , $sql->error);
            }

            if ($query2 = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO user_business_data(email , firstname) VALUES(? , ? )")) {
                $query2->bind_param('ss' , $email , $firstname);
                $query2->execute();
            } else {
                printf('ErrorMessage: %s\n' , $sql->error);
            }
            $query3 = mysqli_query($sql ,"INSERT INTO user_time_stamp_business(time_stamp) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

            $query2->close();
            $query->close();
            $sql->close();
            if ($query && $query2) {
                sleep(3);
                echo "success";
                exit;
            }
```

---

```
                            if (http.responseText == "passed") {
                            works();
                            document.getElementById("main-container").style.transform = "translateY(8%)";
                        } else if (http.responseText == "success") {
                            document.getElementById("alert").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                        }
```

The problem is that it creates a long string AND that it all comes together and not "passed" alone and "success" after

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: they're hashed before that dont worry....

Comment: It's just a small piece of my code

Comment: Create a proper response return, for instance in a JSON-encoded array, and parse that array on return for either errors, success or whatever else you need.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `echo "passed"`, and then `echo "\n" . "success";`.

Afterwards, you'd split the `http.responseText` variable like this: `http.responseText.split("\n")`.
Then you can get the last item of the returned array and use it as your last script response.

This new variable should have what you need:

```
var status = http.responseText.split("\n").reverse()[0];
```

(see [Javascript how to split newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125709/javascript-how-to-split-newline))

Comment: How does it fix the problem that they come together though?

Comment: It's fixed by adding a new line after each status. ("\n")
If you want, you can use any other separator ! Don't forget to update the `.split(SELECTOR)` javascript function