# How to split text in javascript into paragraphs?

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of text:

"Hey is some text some text?

You are some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text

My name is some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text"

I need split in into paragraph and get array from 3 element(I have 3 paragraps above)

Comment: What have you tried so far? A solution to this should be easily searchable. For starters, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125709/javascript-how-to-split-newline/8125757 is the first result when searching "javascript split by newline".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is quite simple. you use the [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function on your string.

You can split it on `\n\n`.

```js
let text=`Hey is some text some text?

You are some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text

My name is some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text`//declare variable
let split=text.split('\n\n') //split up
//logging every new line:
split.forEach(function(item){console.log(item)})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could split on `CR?LF` occurring one or more times:

```js
var input = "Hey is some text some text?\r\n\r\nYou are some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text\r\n\r\nMy name is some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text";
var paragraphs = input.split(/(?:\r?\n)+/);
console.log(paragraphs);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `split()` method and split it by `\n\n`. `\n` Means new line, on your text, there is 2 new line, hence we use `\n\n`.

```js
const text = `Hey is some text some text?

You are some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text

My name is some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text`;

const splittedText = text.split("\n\n");
console.log(splittedText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, spacing is an issue in text from user-generated content. This implementation parses and removes superfluous spacing.

```js
const text = `Hey is some text some text?

You are some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text

My name is some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text`;

const wrappedText = text
  .split('\n')
  .filter(v => v.trim())
  .map(content => `<p>${content.trim()}</p>`)
  .join('\n');
  
console.log(wrappedText);
```